# Why will this code not work? I have spent a long time trying to figure this out

Tags: javascript

This is the start of my JavaScript Code

```
   var para = document.createElement("p");
    var node = document.createTextNode("This is new.");
    para.appendChild(node);
    var element = document.getElementById("test");
    element.appendChild(para);
```

Below is the body

```
          <div id="test"> </div>
```

P.S. I am fairly new to JavaScript and thank you for your time.

Comment: It worked for me.. https://jsfiddle.net/p8oqh4vp/ make sure you included the .js file

Comment: Where are you loading/executing this code? What else have you tried? Can you provide more?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to execute your function on load, otherwise you can't get your element with id `test` form the DOM, because it doesn't exist before the page is loaded:

```
window.onload=function(){
   var para = document.createElement("p");
   var node = document.createTextNode("This is new.");
   para.appendChild(node);
   var element = document.getElementById("test");
   element.appendChild(para);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I used functions before, and I did not realize it had to be a function. Now I know, and I am very thankful for you figuring out my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine using jsfiddle, there may be something else not posted that is interfering with the example you gave.

http://jsfiddle.net/dkLyfzze/

```js
var para = document.createElement("p");
    var node = document.createTextNode("This is new.");
    para.appendChild(node);
    var element = document.getElementById("test");
    element.appendChild(para);
```

```html
<div id="test"> </div>
```